# Jmeter - getting Exception - while running my suite in a new machine

Tags: jmeter

I copied my complete Jmeter folder from one machine to other and tried to run. Stuck with the error - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0. Please help

> INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping
>   org.apache.jmeter.assertions.BSFAssertion
>       INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.extractor.BSFPostProcessor
>       INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.modifiers.BSFPreProcessor
>       INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
>       INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
>       INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
>       INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
>       INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser
>       INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser
>       INFO  - jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils: keytool found at 'keytool'
>       INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder SSL Proxy will use keys that support embedded 3rd
>   party resources in file
>   G:\official\JMeter\apache-jmeter-3.1\bin\proxyserver.jks
>       INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.BSFSampler
>       INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mongodb.config.MongoSourceElement
>       INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mongodb.sampler.MongoScriptSampler
>       INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.timers.BSFTimer
>       INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.BSFListener
>       INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.MonitorHealthVisualizer
>       INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times
>       INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1
>       INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true
>       INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000
>       INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Default base='G:\official\JMeter\apache-jmeter-3.1\bin'
>       INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Loading file: G:\official\JMeter\apache-jmeter-3.1\bin\Cafyne_3.0.jmx
>       INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='G:\official\JMeter\apache-jmeter-3.1\bin'
>       INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2
>       INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8
>       INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 3.1
>       INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: All converter versions present and correct
>       INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Loading file: G:\official\JMeter\apache-jmeter-3.1\bin\Cafyne_3.0.jmx
>       INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager: Settings: Delete null: true Check: true Allow variable: true Save: false Prefix:
>   COOKIE_
>       INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='G:\official\JMeter\apache-jmeter-3.1\bin'
>       ERROR - jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter: Error processing org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Start@71687585
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>       at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Start.startEngine(Start.java:193)     at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Start.startEngine(Start.java:174)   at
>   org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Start.startEngine(Start.java:164)    at
>   org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Start.doAction(Start.java:108)   at
>   org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:62)
>     at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 23):

I know the question is old but I went through the same problem and found no solutions. Then I analyzed the source code of JMeter and I leave here the solution for other people who go through it.

In my case when I created a test plan, by default it was disabled.

After I enabled the test plan (right click -> enable) it started working!

Answer (score 1):

Code is: (failed in testTree.getArray()[0])

```
 HashTree testTree = gui.getTreeModel().getTestPlan();

 JMeter.convertSubTree(testTree);
        if(threadGroupsToRun != null && threadGroupsToRun.length>0) {
            removeThreadGroupsFromHashTree(testTree, threadGroupsToRun);
        }


 testTree.add(testTree.getArray()[0], gui.getMainFrame());
```

It seems that test plan is empty.

can you check G:\official\JMeter\apache-jmeter-3.1\bin\Cafyne_3.0.jmx

maybe file wasn't copied ok

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the two solutions/hints above, the reason is that the first item in the list (as you see below), which is the **Test Plan** itself, was disabled and gray (and usually is not noticed at the first glance).

Just *enable* it and run your test.

[image]